# C# Socket Server communicates only locally

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets

I need to make an application to return me the hours of all customers connected to the socket server.
But my application can only communicate locally.

Example:

If Endpoint Server is: (192.168.0.1, 32000)
    Endpoint Client is: (192.168.0.1, 32000)
    They connect and comunnicate.

But

If Endpoint Server is: (192.168.0.1, 32000)
Endpoint Client is: (192.168.0.2, 32000)
They connect, but not comunnicate.

Server Code:

```
class Server:Sincronia
{
    GetIP getip = new GetIP();

    private Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    private List<Socket> ListaDeClientesSockets = new List<Socket>();   /*Lista de sockets para adicionar clientes*/

    private List<string> ListaDeClients = new List<string>();

    private List<string> ListaDeHoras = new List<string>();

    private const int _BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    private int _PORT;
    private string Ip;
    private byte[] _buffer = new byte[_BUFFER_SIZE];

    public Server(string IP, int port)  /*Construtor para inicialização do IP e da Porta*/
    {
        this.Ip = IP;
        this._PORT = port;
    }

    public  void Connect()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Socket Server ON");
        Console.WriteLine(getip.getIP());
        _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(getip.getIP()), _PORT));
        _serverSocket.Listen(5);
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
    }


    public void ShowAllClients()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("####################### " + ListaDeClientesSockets.Count + " #######################");


        for (int i = 0; i < ListaDeClientesSockets.Count; i++)
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Client : " + j + " IP : " + ListaDeClients[i]);
        }
    }

    private  void CloseConnections()
    {

        foreach (Socket socket in ListaDeClientesSockets)
        {
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            socket.Close();
        }

        _serverSocket.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>AcceptCallback método da classe Server
    /// Evento realizado para aceitar conexões dos clientes adicionando em uma lista genérica
    /// /// </summary>

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult asyncronousResult)
    {
        Socket socket;

        try
        {
            socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(asyncronousResult);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            return;
        }

        ListaDeClientesSockets.Add(socket);
        ListaDeClients.Add(((IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
        socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
        Console.WriteLine("Client Connect " + ((IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
    }


    public void SendToALL(string text)
    {
        foreach(Socket socket in ListaDeClientesSockets.ToList())
        {
            ListaDeHoras.Clear();
            byte[] dataByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

            socket.Send(dataByte);

        }
    }
    /// <summary>ReceiveCallBack método da classe Server
    /// Evento realizado para receber e enviar dados do cliente através de um IASyncResult
    /// </summary>

    private  void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncronousResult)   
    {
        Socket current = (Socket)asyncronousResult.AsyncState;
        int received;

        try
        {
            received = current.EndReceive(asyncronousResult);
        }
        catch (SocketException) /*Catch realizado caso houver perca de conexão com o cliente*/
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Conexão com o cliente " + ((IPEndPoint) current.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString() + " perdida.");
            current.Close();
            ListaDeClients.Remove(((IPEndPoint)current.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
            ListaDeClientesSockets.Remove(current);
            return;
        }

        byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(_buffer, recBuf, received);
        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);

        Console.WriteLine("Received Text: " + text);
        ListaDeHoras.Add(text);


        current.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);

    }
}
```

Program Server code:

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Servidor";

        Server server = new Server("localhost", 8000);

        server.Connect();
        while (true)
        {
            string text = Console.ReadLine();

            if (text == "mostrar")
                server.ShowAllClients();
            else
                server.SendToALL(text);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
   class Client
{
    Socket socketClient;

    static int port = 8000;
    static string localhostIP = "127.0.0.1";

    private const int _BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    private byte[] _buffer = new byte[_BUFFER_SIZE];

    private string IP;

    public Client(string ip)
    {
        this.IP = ip;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        IPEndPoint endp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
        try
        {
            socketClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socketClient.BeginConnect(endp, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCALLBACK), socketClient);
            Receive(socketClient);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    private void ConnectCALLBACK(IAsyncResult assynresult)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)assynresult.AsyncState;
            Console.WriteLine("Conectado");
            client.EndConnect(assynresult);
        }
        catch(SocketException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Falta de conexão com o servidor, verifique sua conexão.");
        }

    }

    public void Receive(Socket socket)
    {
        try
        {
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncronousResult)
    {
        Socket current = (Socket)asyncronousResult.AsyncState;
        int received;

        try
        {
            received = current.EndReceive(asyncronousResult);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            return;
        }

        byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(_buffer, recBuf, received);
        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);

        if(text == "clock")
        {
            string horas = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
            byte[] sended = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(horas);
            current.Send(sended);
        }


        current.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
    }
}
```

I need the server type "clock" and this is sent to all clients.

And so that clients receive, clients send to the server their respective hours.

Comment: Have you tested the port in server whether it is behind the firewall or just open for all network looks like the port you are using for you communication is behind a firewall

Comment: Ja is released the door, but it did not work.

Comment: Assuming you have configured the IP addresses for your server and client correctly, then you have a network configuration issue. If you haven't, you have a typographical error in your code. Either way, the question is off-topic. If you believe it's something other than one of these two possibilities, fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hum.. i'm try testing, but always of the same, I get only local

Answer (score 0):

just replace your client start function with the following

```
public void Start()
    {
        IPEndPoint endp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
        try
        {
            socketClient = new Socket(endp, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socketClient.BeginConnect(endp, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCALLBACK), socketClient);
            Receive(socketClient);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: On socketClient = new Socket(end,...) the endp cannot convert from "System.Net.IPEndpoint" to "System.Sockets.AddressFamily"